# Cruisecontrol.net project settings with dynamic parameters

Tags: continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net

I am trying to set up CruiseControl.NET (1.6.7981.1) so that each developer can choose which source-control branch to build from.  I have encountered the following problems.

1. I have not found a way to set `<artifactDirectory>` and `<workingDirectory>` project parameters through dynamic parameters.
2. CruiseControl.NET is not replacing the dynamic parameter tokens, e.g. `$[branchName]` is not replaced in `<artifactDirectory>C:/ci/$[branchName]<artifactDirectory>`.

Is there a way to have a single project with multiple artifact and working directories chosen by end users?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not use dynamic parameters in `<artifactDirectory>` and `<workingDirectory>`. The documentation states:

> Parameters can be used for tasks/publishers, source control blocks and labellers. [...]
>   Not all items allow the use of dynamic parameters.

If you are willing to relax on the single-project constraint, you could use the [Configuration Preprocessor](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Configuration_Preprocessor) to define and apply a parameterized project template.